# Why am I seeing "-1 votes remaining"?

Tags: bug, vote-to-delete

I just saw this when I tried voting to delete an answer. I [searched](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=-1%20votes%20remaining) on meta but I couldn't find any duplicate question.

Is this a bug or something?

[image]

Comment: Did you possibly use all your votes *and then drop below a threshold for extra vote*?

Comment: @3ventic Yes I used them all but this should seen it like "0 votes remaining" IMO..

Comment: I think the problem is that it's not supposed to show you the confirmation dialog when you're out of votes - only the error message. At least, that makes more sense.

Comment: I still see [this message](http://i.imgur.com/fmhsAhW.png) by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was observed by other users too; the software did not correctly account for the delete votes cast by the user on own posts. Eventually, the bug report [Negative number of delete votes left?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/19444) on meta.Mathematics got  attention of a developer, and the behavior was at least partially corrected:

> the next build will show zero instead of a negative number if you have < 0.